# How to track the SQL query launched in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, monitoring

Please specify whether it is possible to track the SQL in Oracle launched queries?
If yes, you can, how to do it?

The essence of this, there are several employees, and you need to understand who and that runs, that is, some kind of username of users, where the start-up requests will be visible, who launched when I started, and how much time went to the execution of the query.
If I do not understand my question quite enough, ask. Thank you all for your attention!

Comment: Your quastion is about administraion on a server. You should ask it on https://serverfault.com

Comment: You need to use [auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html#GUID-94381464-53A3-421B-8F13-BD171C867405).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about real time performance monitoring of your database, then this will depend on a number of factors, including exactly which version of Oracle you have. Oracle is generally tooled to provide the kind of metrics you're talking about, but the most useful ones (in my experience) may require additional software and additional option licenses to make them visible.

SQL Developer has some basic functionality within its DBA connection options. It can also make ASH and ADDM reports more accessible. Other tools like Oracle Enterprise Manager and Foglight for Oracle provide more detailed metrics over time.

More recent versions of Oracle have more options built-in. Your best bet is to start with Oracle's "2 Day DBA + Performance Tuning Guide" for your version of the database:

- [Oracle 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tdppt/index.html)
- [Oracle 18c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tdppt/index.html)
- [Oracle 12cR2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tdppt/index.html)
- [Oracle 12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPPT/toc.htm)